# Getting Cannot Connect to the Azure Devops account on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs

Getting cannot to the Azure Devops account:https://dev.azure.com error on Visual studio 2022 while creating Load test wizard on visual studio to do test my website with concurrent users.

[image]

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for valuable reply. Can this be done using VS 2019 or prior version? I need to simulate 100K users for testing one application, so that i can use Cloud Load test agents instead of Local VS agents.

Comment: Yes. You can do it via VS 2019 or prior version. It will have complete feature of load test.If the answer can give you some help, you may consider accept it.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?  Can you help us confirm if vs 2019 can work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Test to use the Load Test Wizard in VS2022 and reproduce the same issue:

[image]

Refer to this doc: [Create a load test project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2022)

> Web performance and load test functionality is deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where web performance and load testing will be fully available.  To reduce the impact on users, some minimum support is still available in Visual Studio 2022. (You can run existing web/load tests, but the templates to create new tests were removed.)

The cause of this issue is that VS2022 no longer supports the full function of Load testing.

Therefore its ability to connect to Azure DevOps is limited. We are not able to connect to Azure DevOps successfully.